# How do internet services determine the device type?

Tags: router, proxy

I'm at my partner's lodgings at her university, and they use a proxy (I think, at least) running Ask4. I don't know the exact structure of their network, but it's likely to be some sort of proxy. The Ask4 service only allows 5 devices to be registered to a room at a time, however when I connected a  router to an ethernet port, a page appeared stating that I'd connected a router, which would incur an extra charge.

My original plan was to spoof the MAC address of an already-registered device on the router (running DD-WRT), however this made no difference. After reading that this went against the terms of service, I thought better and removed the router.

My question is this: how can services, whatever they may be, determine what kind of device an attached MAC is? In this case, how can the proxy server determine that I've connected a router? Does it to something as naive as a `tcptraceroute`, or is there a standard that I don't know about to determine device type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute **[nmap](http://nmap.org)** and try **Operating System guess** for your router. I believe this plus MAC address ranges matching is what they are using to determine device type.

```
nmap -O your_ip
```

In my case:

- **192.168.1.1**

  - router/firewall
  - result: ZyXEL ZyWALL 2 firewall
  - OK
- **192.168.1.7**

  - router
  - result: No exact OS matches for host, MAC Address: ** (SMC Networks)
  - nearly match - SMCWBR14-G2
- **192.168.1.200**

  - client pc
  - result: Linux 2.6.X
  - nearly match - CentOS 5.8

Technique used is called **[OS fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_fingerprinting)**

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways a device can give itself away, but the most obvious one is transmitting on the wrong pins on a 10Mbit or 100Mbit network.  Nodes (PCs) and network devices (e.g. routers) transmit on different pins and the university system probably detects that.